# Meaning of the 'single white lighting bolt on black background' symbol in JoJo Rabbit?

Tags: analysis, realism, reference, jojo-rabbit

There were two different 'single lightning bolt' symbols.

The first on is a badge awarded within the hitlerjugend afaik:
[image: White bolt on (round) red background]

The second one has different colors and is portrayed on a flag. What's its meaning?

[image: White bolt on black background]

Comment: I haven't watched this movie yet, but are there any real swastikas in the movie? If not, then this sign would be a substitute to probably avoid some censorships, etc.

Comment: There were swastikas and other symbols related to the hitlerjugend. They were realistic and appropriate for the context as far as I can judge. Thats why I'm wondering about this one in particular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This particular symbol and color combination would be the *Deutsches Jungvolk in der Hitler Jugend* (German Youngsters in the Hitler Youth).

> The ***Deutsches Jungvolk*** in der Hitler Jugend (**DJ**, also **DJV**; German for "German Youngsters in the Hitler Youth") was the separate section for boys aged 10 to 14 of the Hitler Youth organisation in Nazi Germany. Through a programme of outdoor activities, parades and sports, it aimed to indoctrinate its young members in the tenets of Nazi ideology. Membership became fully compulsory for eligible boys in 1939. By the end of World War II, some had become child soldiers. After the end of the war in 1945, both the Deutsches Jungvolk and its parent organization, the Hitler Youth, ceased to exist.
> ...
> The emblem of the DJ was a **white Sieg rune on a black background**, which symbolised "victory". This was worn on the uniform in the form of a cloth badge, sewn onto the upper-left sleeve of the shirt.
>   <sub>*source:* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_Jungvolk)</sub>

The 'flag' or banner shown in your question's second image fits the description of the badge/decoration used by this younger division of the *hitlerjugend*. This fits with the age of the title character

Answer (score 5):

This is a [sig rune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sowil%C5%8D#Armanen_runes). In National Socialism, the single sig rune was an emblem of the Hitler Youth. The [double sig rune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runic_insignia_of_the_Schutzstaffel) was used by the *Schutzstaffel* (SS).

Note that the use of both the single and the double sig rune may be liable to prosecution in Germany today.